# How to insert a symbol infront of a number in html?

Tags: javascript

I have a code like the given below to insert a symbol :

```
var price1  = (array[0]);

$( "ul.additemsprice" ).prepend( "<li class='additemprice'></li>" );
$("ul.additemsprice").find('li.additemprice').html(price1);
```

In this code, I want to insert a `$` sign in-front of `price1` before inserting into the html tag `<li>`

Can anyone say how to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with PHP or JavaScript? You have a PHP tag but this is JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: there is no php tag in this ?

Comment: i ma doing this in js

Comment: Simple [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be done like below:-

```
$("ul.additemsprice").find('li.additemprice').html('$'+price1);
```

```js
var price1 = "20";
$("ul.additemsprice").find('li.additemprice').html('$'+price1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="additemsprice">
  
  <li class="additemprice"></li>
  
  </ul>
```

Comment: @Divya  glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

```js
var price1  = 40;
$( "ul.additemsprice" ).prepend( "<li class='additemprice'>$"+ price1 +"</li>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="additemsprice">
</ul>
```

You can achieve this in one instruction doing like this:

```
var price1  = (array[0]);
$( "ul.additemsprice" ).prepend( "<li class='additemprice'>$"+ price1 +"</li>" );
```

Comment: Much more efficient. You wouldn't mail somebody an empty envelope and then later drive to their house to put the letter in it.